# I am trying to install a .exe file using powershell. But I cannot find a way to in select check box while installation. Anyone know how to do it?

Tags: powershell, netbeans

I am trying to automate the installation of Netbeans using PowerShell.

```
$exePath = "C:\Users\adminuser\Downloads\Apache-NetBeans-17-bin-windows-x64.exe"
Start-Process $exePath
```

Wait for the "Next" button to become available:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 20
#while (-not [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Wait("{TAB}")) {}

# Click on the "Next" button
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{Enter}")
```

Next I need to select the checkbox but I didn't find the code to select it.

Please find the below image for reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kziyq.jpg)

Comment: Using `Apache-NetBeans-17-bin-windows-x64.exe --help` reports that there is a `--silent` parameter. I do not know it that will get past the licensing or not.

Comment: Someone made this for NetBeans 13: https://silentinstallhq.com/apache-netbeans-ide-13-silent-install-how-to-guide/ Maybe this be of help